# AnyLogic and need to simulate a bouncing ball

Tags: anylogic

I'm new to AnyLogic and need to simulate a bouncing ball which is restricted in movement through a box (ie ball should bounce off walls). Just needed help with the transitions equations/coding or algorithm in order to achieve this.

I'm able to get it to bounce, its the restrictions that have me stuck.

Answer (score 0):

There's an example in Anylogic called billiard balls which is an excellent example for bouncing balls, since the balls bounce and they are restricted to a box. So it's basically what you want.